# MySQL calculate days

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table with orders like this:

```
+----------+-------------+------------+
| order_id | customer_id | order_date |
+----------+-------------+------------+
|    404   |     16      | 2006-11-04 |
|    726   |     16      | 2007-11-01 |
|    440   |     16      | 2010-03-15 |
|    515   |     16      | 2011-04-29 |
|    539   |     16      | 2011-11-01 |
|    293   |     89      | 2001-08-28 |
|    156   |     89      | 2002-05-03 |
|    238   |     89      | 2003-09-15 |
|    299   |     28      | 2001-10-26 |
|    314   |     28      | 2004-03-18 |
|    142   |     79      | 2002-01-21 |
|    313   |     12      | 2004-03-11 |
|    388   |     12      | 2005-11-22 |
|    507   |     12      | 2007-03-27 |
|    286   |     14      | 2006-04-17 |
|    200   |     14      | 2008-05-25 |
|    130   |     14      | 2009-06-24 |
|    527   |     19      | 2011-05-14 |
|    298   |     76      | 2001-10-20 |
|    165   |     76      | 2002-07-27 |
|    212   |     11      | 2003-02-17 |
|    412   |     11      | 2006-08-02 |
|    423   |     11      | 2007-03-28 |
|    388   |     10      | 2005-01-07 |
|    390   |     65      | 2006-06-07 |
|    44    |     65      | 2008-01-07 |
|    269   |     16      | 2008-02-25 |
|    413   |     14      | 2007-12-01 |
|    675   |     14      | 2007-09-11 |
|    260   |     14      | 2009-10-20 |
+----------+-------------+------------+
```

Now I need a query which give me a list like this:

```
+-------------+------------+------------+------+
| customer_id |    date1   |    date2   | days |
+-------------+------------+------------+------+
|     16      | 2006-11-04 | 2007-11-01 | 362  |
|     16      | 2007-11-01 | 2010-03-15 | 865  |
|     16      | 2010-03-15 | 2011-04-29 | 410  |
|     16      | 2011-04-29 | 2011-11-01 | 186  |
|     89      | 2001-08-28 | 2002-05-03 | 248  |
|     89      | 2002-05-03 | 2003-09-15 | 500  |
+-------------+------------+------------+------+
```

The column days are the timespan in days from one order to the next order for each customer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT A.customer_id, 
    A.date as date1, 
    B.date as date2, 
    datediff(B.date, A.date) as days
FROM (select @curRowA := @curRowA + 1 AS row_number, 
        customer_id, 
        date from 
        orders 
    ORDER BY customer_id asc, date desc) A
INNER JOIN (select @curRowB := @curRowB + 1 AS row_number, 
            customer_id, 
            date from orders 
    ORDER BY customer_id asc, date desc offset 1) B
ON A.row_number = B.row_number AND A.customer_id = B.customer_id
```

As you can see, I have a subquery that selects all records from orders table, but adds row_number into A, then I do the same thing but just shifted one row down (offset 1) and create B. Then I just join A and B and you get the results.

```
A
    row_id, customer, date
    1, 1, d1
    2, 1, d2
    3, 1, d3
    4, 2, d4
    5, 2, d5

B
    row_id, customer, date
    1, 1, d2
    2, 1, d3
    3, 2, d4
    4, 2, d5
```

when A and B are joined

```
result
customer, date1, date2
1, d1, d2
1, d2, d3
2, d4, d5
```

UPDATE: As per Marc's comment, it might be better to try to fetch date2 from correlated query (by customer) where you select dates which are smaller than date and limit that result to 1 row.

Comment: Could just use a correlated subquery to fetch per-user rows greater than the date in the parent row, with a limit of 1. That'd simplify things greatly.

Comment: You are right..and it would probably perform better. This came to my mind first, so I wrote it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can pls try this one, very well tested...

```
SELECT distinct(c1.customer_id) as 'customer_id',
```

`(select min(c2.order_date) from tmp2 c2 where c2.customer_id=c1.customer_id) as date1, (select max(c2.order_date) from tmp2 c2 where c2.customer_id=c1.customer_id) as date2, (DATEDIFF( (select max(c40.order_date) from tmp2 c40 where c40.customer_id=c1.customer_id) , (select min(c40.order_date) from tmp2 c40 where c40.customer_id=c1.customer_id) )) as 'days' FROM`tmp2`as c1 WHERE 1`